# Swift: NSURL with parameters is invalid

Tags: swift, google-maps, share, nsurl

This is my code to share a Google Maps link with a UIActivityVieController:

```
 if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://maps.google.com/?q=<\(myLatitude)>,<\(myLongitude)>") {
        let objectsToShare = [alertMessage, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        //New Excluded Activities Code
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This link is not valid though; the if statement is not called. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your NSURL should look like this:

```
let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://maps.google.com/?q=\(myLatitude),\(myLongitude)")
```

To use a string inside a string you should write

```
"My string \(otherString)";
```